# best place to put the logic in a SRP way dealing with Redux sagas against Firestore,

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga, reducers

Learning more about [Redux Sagas](https://redux-saga.js.org/) and the Reducer pattern and want to ask for how to abstract my workflow in a sensible way.

I have a backend Firestore collections of "tags" documents like this very simple.
A Tag is a json object like {"name": "Bmw"}.

When a Tag is changed, modified or deleted I use the [Saga Channel](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels/) to listen on changes like this.

Here's the code simple setup:

```
function* tagsListenerSaga() {
    const firebase = yield getContext('firebase');
    const ref = firebase.db.collection(FIRESTORE.GLOBAL_TAGS).orderBy(FIRESTORE.NAME);
    const channel = yield call(metaEventListener, ref);
    try {
        while (true) {
            const querySnapshot = yield take(channel);
            const addedTags = [];
            const modifiedTags = [];
            const deletedTags = [];

            querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(doc => {
                if (doc.type === 'added') {
                    console.log('added : ', doc.doc.data());
                    addedTags.push({
                        ...doc.doc.data(),
                        id: doc.doc.id,
                    });
                }
                if (doc.type === 'modified') {
                    console.log('modified : ', doc.doc.data());
                    modifiedTags.push({
                        ...doc.doc.data(),
                        id: doc.doc.id,
                    });
                }
                if (doc.type === 'removed') {
                    console.log('removed : ', doc.doc.data());
                    deletedTags.push({
                        ...doc.doc.data(),
                        id: doc.doc.id,
                    });
                }
            });
            if (addedTags.length) {
                yield put(setTagsAdded(addedTags));
            }
            if (modifiedTags.length) {
                // yield put(setTagsModified(modifiedTags));
            }
            if (deletedTags.length) {
                // yield put(setTagsDeleted(deletedTags));
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        if (yield cancelled()) {
            console.log('error');
            channel.close();
        }
    }
}

const metaEventListener = ref => {
    const channel = eventChannel(emitter => {
        const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(doc => {
            emitter(doc);
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    });
    return channel;
};

export default function* watchTagsMetaRequests() {
    yield takeLatest(globalActionTypes.START_LISTEN_TAGS, tagsListenerSaga);
}
```

As you see in the Saga I respond to Firebase `querySnapshot` and calling `yield put(setTagsAdded(addedTags));` to the `reducer` to save the `addedTags`.

In the Saga I have all three:

```
    if (addedTags.length) {
        yield put(setTagsAdded(addedTags));
    }
    if (modifiedTags.length) {
        // yield put(setTagsModified(modifiedTags));
    }
    if (deletedTags.length) {
        // yield put(setTagsDeleted(deletedTags));
    }
```

To handle delegate the data toward the `reducer` and I must somewhere add this `tag` changes to the `reducer` state.
Dose it make sense to insted send the `querySnapshot` to the `reducer` and inside `reducer` search through the `tags` map and add/delete/update `tags` or,

should/could the Saga `select` the `reducer` state needed to do this and then the Saga do the `yield put..` with an updated `tags` map. What happens regarding transactions state and atomicy here?

I want to adhere the Single responsibility principle (SRP) in the best way for future best modulations
pros and cons please?